# Why the copy constructor is not called?

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, copy-constructor, return-value-optimization

In this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(): egg(0) {}
        Foo(const Foo& other): egg(1) {}

        int egg;
};

Foo bar() {
    Foo baz;
    baz.egg = 3;
    return baz;
}

int main(void) {
    Foo spam(bar());
    cout << spam.egg;
    return 0;
}
```

the output is `3`, while I expected it to be `1`.

That means the copy constructor is not called in the line `Foo spam(bar())`.

I guess it's because the `bar` function doesn't return a reference.

Could you please explain what's really going on at the initialization of `spam`?

I apologize in advance if that's a dumb question.

Thanks!

Comment: You would be correct...because baz is a temporary that is destroyed when it leaves scope of the bar function.

Comment: Search for Return Value Optimization (RVO). It is one of the few circumstances where c++ is allowed to skip calling the copy constructor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Copy/move elision is the only allowed exception to the so-called "*as-if*" rule, which normally constrains the kinds of transformations (e.g. optimizations) that a compiler is allowed to perform on a program.

The rule is intended to allow compilers to perform any optimization they wish as long as the transformed program would work "*as if*" it was the original one. However, there is one important exception.

Per paragraph 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, **even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects**. [...] This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>     non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified
>     type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>     the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
>
> [...]
>
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
>
> [...]

In other words, you should never rely on a copy constructor or move constructor being called or *not* being called in the cases for which the provisions of 12.8/31 apply.

Comment: @AndyPowl: Thanks! That's what I was searching for.

Comment: The quoted part of the spec only gets rid of one of the two copies here (the copy from `baz` to the unnamed temporary holding the return value of `bar()`).  The second copy (from the temporary to `spam`) is omitted as allowed by the 3rd bullet point in the quoted section, which you left out of your quote...